# Actionscript drawing w/clear button

Tags: flash, button, actionscript, ellipse

I'm following example Lesson 4 out of Actionscript classroom in a book, but modifying it by adding a CLEAR button to the stage.

Whenever I test all of the functions work, but, I am able to draw over the top of my button. Ideally when the user is drawing, the colors should be going underneath the button.

In the timeline I have layers for the Background, Button, and Actions. I've added the coding below to help address the issue quicker. Thanks!

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Ellipse extends MovieClip {

        // constructor
        public function Ellipse(w:Number=40,h:Number=40,color:Number=0xff0000) {
            graphics.beginFill(color);
            graphics.drawEllipse(0, 0, w, h);
            graphics.endFill();
        }

    } // end class Ellipse

} // end package




import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var color:Number;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);

function startDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void {
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, makeShapes);
color = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
}

function stopDrawing(e:MouseEvent):void {
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, makeShapes);
}

function makeShapes(e:MouseEvent):void {
var ellipse:Ellipse = new Ellipse(10, 10, color);
stage.addChild(ellipse);
ellipse.x = mouseX;
ellipse.y = mouseY;
}


btnClear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearBoard);

function clearBoard(e:MouseEvent)
{
    for (var i:int = stage.numChildren-1; i >= 1; i--) {
   stage.removeChildAt (i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addChild` adds items to the top of the display list, so when you are adding your ellipses to the stage, you are adding them in front of your button and movie. That is, your movie (with the button) is at index 0, but your shapes are added at index 1 and higher. One solution would be to add them below the movie instead, using `addChildAt`:

```
var shapeIndex:uint = 0;
function makeShapes(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var ellipse:Ellipse = new Ellipse(10, 10, color);
    stage.addChildAt(ellipse, shapeIndex); // add the shape starting at 0, and count up from there
    // this will keep the movie at the top of the stage's display list
    shapeIndex++;
    ellipse.x = mouseX;
    ellipse.y = mouseY;
}
```

An alternative solution is to first make a container clip, and then add the shape's to this container clip instead. This allows you to easily control where the shapes appear:

```
var container : Sprite = new Sprite();
stage.addChildAt(container, 0); // add the container to the bottom of the stage
// now we can just easily add our shapes to the container, and they will all be behind the main movie.
function makeShapes(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var ellipse:Ellipse = new Ellipse(10, 10, color);
    container.addChild(ellipse);
    shapeIndex++;
    ellipse.x = mouseX;
    ellipse.y = mouseY;
}
```

And this actually makes other things such as clearing your screen easier. You can simply remove and recreate the container clip:

```
function clearBoard(e:MouseEvent)
{
    stage.removeChild(container);
    container = new Sprite();
    stage.addChildAt(container, 0);
}
```

Comment: Note that it's considered bad practice to add things directly to `stage`. Instead, consider adding them to `root`.

Comment: Thanks Mike! You've been more than helpful!